# Laravel convert array to single object when one related model is specified

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm working inside a Laravel 9 project. I have a model called `Affiliate` which defines a **hasMany** relationship on my `AffiliateProduct` model. My `AffiliateProduct` defines a **hasOne** relationship for both a `Product` and `Country`.

An affiliate can have multiple products, but when the related product and country model are specified, I'd like to return a single entry instead of `AffiliateProduct` being an array, for example, right now I'd have to do:

```php
$affiliate[0]->products->country
```

But I'd like to just be able to do:

```php
$affiliate->products->country
```

Here's my query:

```php
// get affiliate
$affiliate = Affiliate::where('aff_id', $request->input('AffId'))
                        ->where('allow_submission', true)
                        ->where('is_enabled', true)
                        ->with([
                        'products' => function ($query) use ($productSlug, $countrySlug) {
                            $query->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($productSlug) {
                                $q->where('slug', $productSlug)
                                    ->orWhere('is_default', true)
                                    ->where('is_enabled', true);
                            })->whereHas('country', function ($q) use ($countrySlug) {
                                $q->where('slug', $countrySlug)
                                    ->orWhere('is_default', true)
                                    ->where('is_enabled', true);
                            });
                        },
                        'products.product',
                        'products.country'
                        ])
                        ->first();
```

And this is what my current JSON output looks like:

```json
{
    "Result": "Accepted",
    "Message": "Yay!",
    "Model": {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "company_id": 1,
        "aff_id": "test",
        "description": "test",
        "api_hash": "test",
        "allow_submission": true,
        "is_favourited": false,
        "is_default": false,
        "is_enabled": true,
        "last_used_at": null,
        "created_at": "2023-02-01T15:19:40.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-01T15:19:40.000000Z",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "is_deleting": false,
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "user_id": 3,
                "company_id": 1,
                "affiliate_id": 2,
                "country_id": 1,
                "product_id": 1,
                "serve_method_id": 3,
                "application_form_id": null,
                "pingtree_group_id": 1,
                "callback_url": null,
                "callback_condition": null,
                "duplicate_response": null,
                "created_at": "2023-02-01T15:39:01.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-02-01T15:39:01.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "is_deleting": false,
                "product": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "company_id": 1,
                    "name": "Payday",
                    "slug": "payday",
                    "description": "Support brokering loan leads via an application.",
                    "is_default": true,
                    "is_enabled": true,
                    "created_at": "2023-02-01T15:19:39.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2023-02-01T15:19:39.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "is_deleting": false
                },
                "country": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "company_id": 1,
                    "country_code": "GB",
                    "calling_code": "44",
                    "name": "United Kingdom",
                    "slug": "united-kingdom",
                    "description": "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland",
                    "currency": "GBP",
                    "is_default": true,
                    "is_enabled": true,
                    "created_at": "2023-02-01T15:19:39.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2023-02-01T15:19:39.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "is_deleting": false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Also, any tips on potentially improving my query would be appreciated.

Comment: Using `->first()` will return single `Affiliate` model , and you already done that at the end of your query. And to limit the fetched `AffiliateProduct` , try this package https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Comment: Yes, that's correct, there can only ever be one `Affiliate`. But this wasn't my question. The question is how can I return just one `AffiliateProduct` based on the result of the nested queries. By default an affiliate can have multiple affiliate products, but when the nested product and country are found, I want to convert to one.

Comment: Does [has-one-of-many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many) isn't accomodating your need?